# Finding A Basis For Subspace Of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Find a basis for $U=\{A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}: A=A^t\}$

Now It easy to see that becuase  $$\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
a & c \\
b & d 
\end{pmatrix}$$ We have $$\begin{pmatrix} 
a & c \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}\in Span\{\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\}$$

But how do I slove it using system of linear equations? Do I need to look at

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 
x & y \\
z & t 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
a & c \\
b & d 
\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Your matrix is not equal to the span of your proposed set, but is rather an element of it. I'm also not sure what you mean by "how do I show it". Show what exactly?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620757/find-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-symmetric-matrices-with-an-order-of-n-tim and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138944/questions-on-symmetric-matrices and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194415/how-is-this-a-basis-for-the-vector-space-of-symmetric-2x2-matrices and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870519/prove-basis-for-symmetric-matrix and probably quite a few others.

Comment: @user23793 edited, I mean how do I solve the qeustion using a system of linear equations

Answer (score 1):

For $\Bbb{R}^{2\times2}$ you have the standard basis
$$b_1:=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\quad
b_2:=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
b_3:=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},\qquad
b_4:=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
With respect to this basis, the subspace $U$ is the zero locus of the linear equation $x_2=x_3$. This means $\{b_1,b_2+b_3,b_4\}$ is a basis for $U$, as you already found.